# Streamlit: How to control the second instance and access locally hosted services?

Tags: caching, memcached, streamlit

I have a streamlit app that is fully cached. In fact, I am using a 3rd party caching system running on a local port, and I can see that the cache is being used.

However, streamlit runs two distinct instances when it is started up:

```
# Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2.0, Running Ubuntu

  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:8501
  Network URL: http://172.21.141.16:8501
```

From my print statements, it appears as if only the local instance is accessing my cache hosted on a local port.

Simultaneously, the Network URL instance **does not leverage the cache hosted on the local port at all** and recalculates all of the long running processes that are happily caching themselves on the local side.

I am not exposing this system outside of a virtual machine, so I don't care about security.

---

My question amounts to: how do I force or eliminate the streamlit's double-instance runtime situation  such that all running instances (if there must be two) are able to access the locally running cache?

At the same time, though, I need to preserve streamlit's network topology, as I can only access the external URL (http://172.21.141.16:8501) from the Windows host operating system.

*Note that I am using a locally running cache because I want to access and accumulate cached values from multiple processes -- some front and some back.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streamlit isn't running two instances, the URLs are indicating the relative URL (localhost) and your computer's public/network IP address.